# How to get Select Many from relation navigation key using LINQ/Lambda?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, plinq

We have different relationship with Entity models. I want to find the below.

Table: **Customer**

```
[Table("CustomerTable")]
public partial class CustomerTable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Country { get; set; }


    public virtual CompanyTable CompanyTable { get; set; }

    public virtual CurrencyTable CurrencyTable { get; set; }

    public virtual LoginTable LoginTable { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProcessTable> ProcessTables { get; set; }

}
```

Table:  **CompanyTable**

```
[Table("CompanyTable")]
public partial class CompanyTable
{

    public CompanyTable()
    {
        CustomerTables = new HashSet<CustomerTable>();
        ProcessTables = new HashSet<ProcessTable>();
        DateRegistered = DateTime.Now;
        PaymentDate = DateTime.Now;

    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerTable> CustomerTables { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProcessTable> ProcessTables { get; set; }

}
```

Table: **Process**

```
[Table("ProcessTable")]
public partial class ProcessTable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerTable")]
    [Required]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("CompanyTable")]
    [Required]
    public int Company { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public int TotalPayment { get; set; }
    public int PaymentReceived { get; set; }// Store time of create process,1st time only

    public virtual CompanyTable CompanyTable { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerTable CustomerTable { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProcessPaymentMapping> 
    ProcessPaymentMappingList { get; set; }
}
```

Table: **ProcessPaymentMapping** ( For payment History )

```
[Table("ProcessPaymentMapping")]
public partial class ProcessPaymentMapping
{
    public ProcessPaymentMapping()
    {
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        isDeleted = false;
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProcessTable")]
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal PaymentReceived { get; set; }

    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public bool isDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual ProcessTable ProcessTable { get; set; }
}
```

I want to display customer wise Record with Remaining Payment & Total payment for process.

- Company has rights to create new Customer. ( That time we are storing
  the Total payment and initial given payment from customer, same time
  storing the initial value to  ProcessPaymentMapping  Table)
- One Company has multiple processes.
- One process has multiple ProcessPaymentMapping records.
- One customer has one or many process that was registered by company,
- ProcessPaymentMapping table stored the payment History with date
- Each time customer paid for the running process.

Process table has stored only Total amount value at time of new process registerd by company

I want to display customer wise payment as below.

```
Index | Customer Name | Process ID | Total Amount | Paid Amount | Remaining Amount 
1. | Jhon Michel  | 544545 | 150 USD | 100 USD | 50 USD
2. | Arena Bosch  | 544546 | 200 USD | 50 USD | 150 USD
```

Like wise.
How to do using group by in entity..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            CompanyTable companyTable = new CompanyTable();

            var results = (from ct in companyTable.CustomerTables
                          join pt in companyTable.ProcessTables on ct.Id equals pt.CustomerId
                          select new { customerName = ct.CompanyTable.Name, processId = pt.Id, totalPayment = pt.TotalPayment, paidAmount = pt.PaymentReceived, remainingAmount = pt.TotalPayment - pt.PaymentReceived }).ToList();
```

---

If you also want index then use this

```
            var results = (from ct in companyTable.CustomerTables
                          join pt in companyTable.ProcessTables on ct.Id equals pt.CustomerId
                          select new { customerName = ct.CompanyTable.Name, processId = pt.Id, totalPayment = pt.TotalPayment, paidAmount = pt.PaymentReceived, remainingAmount = pt.TotalPayment - pt.PaymentReceived })
                          .Select((x,i) => new { index = i, customerName = x.customerName, processId = x.processId, totalPayment = x.totalPayment,  paidAmount = x.paidAmount, remainingAmount = x.remainingAmount})
                          .ToList();
```

---

Adding a GroupBy.  Not exactly sure how to handle the three amount.  Took a guess

```
            var results = (from ct in companyTable.CustomerTables
                          join pt in companyTable.ProcessTables on ct.Id equals pt.CustomerId
                          select new { customerName = ct.CompanyTable.Name, processId = pt.Id, totalPayment = pt.TotalPayment, paidAmount = pt.PaymentReceived, remainingAmount = pt.TotalPayment - pt.PaymentReceived })
                          .GroupBy(x => x.processId)\
                           .Select((x,i) => new { index = i, customerName = x.FirstOrDefault().customerName, processId = x.FirstOrDefault().processId, 
                               totalPayment = x.Sum(y => y.totalPayment),  paidAmount = x.Sum(y => y.paidAmount), remainingAmount = x.Sum(y => y.remainingAmount)})
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: actually there required to groupby on ProcessPaymentMapping table, there will have multiple entry with processid and multiple recieved payments on different dates.. we have to make sum of them and then make difference on Process Table's Total payment to know remaining..